# Does not delete on-line list - Android REST Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I use retrofit to communicate with REST Api in the Android application. The display of data downloaded from JSON works very well. I wants to delete data. I used ClickListener, and it removes data from the server, but does not delete it from the on-line list. How to do it after reloading reloads the list?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

    viewHolder.productNameTextView.setText(arrayListProducts.get(i).getName());

    viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + arrayListProducts.get(i).getName());

            Toast.makeText(context, "Kliknąłeś: " + arrayListProducts.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete: " + arrayListProducts.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RetrofitRequest.delete(arrayListProducts.get(i).getId());

        }
    });
```

When I run the application again, the list gets a new one and there are no deleted data, but I want it to be removed just after clicking on the basket and a list was shown without this deleted data.
Do you have an example with GitHub where does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a callback from Retrofit which contains `onSuccess`
If it goes on that, you can simply remove the object from list of data and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
viewHolder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Delete: " + arrayListProducts.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        RetrofitRequest.delete(arrayListProducts.get(i).getId());
        arrayListProducts.remove(i);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: cool!! it works. Do you have any example of how you can do it with callback from Retrofit?

Comment: I don't really know how your Retrofit builder is implemented.. Neither your interfaces. As it is now, the code works but is not okay because from user perspective the item is deleted, but if the request fails it should not... If you get my point